# API Platform - Unable to generate an IRI for the item of type

Tags: api, rest, symfony

I have created an API using symfony 6 and API Platform 3.
For the first entities, everything was fine but I have an error now when I do a GET collection
request for `User` entity (`api/users`) :

`Unable to generate an IRI for the item of type \"App\\Entity\\User\"`

So why this happens and how to fix it ?

Here is an excerpt from my `User` entity :

```
...
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Delete(),
        new Get(),
        new Put(),
        new Patch(),
        new GetCollection(),
        new Post()
    ],
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['read:User']]
)]
#[ApiFilter(OrderFilter::class)]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
class User
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(unique: true, nullable: false)]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue('NONE')]
    #[Groups(groups: ['read:User'])]
    private ?string $username = null;

    #[ORM\OneToOne(mappedBy: 'user', cascade: ['all'])]
    #[Groups(groups: ['read:User'])]
    private ?Employee $employee = null;

    #[ORM\Column(name: 'first_name', length: 255, nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(groups: ['read:User'])]
    private ?string $firstName = null;

    #[ORM\Column(name: 'last_name', length: 255, nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(groups: ['read:User'])]
    private ?string $lastName = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'username', targetEntity: UserRole::class, cascade: ['all'], orphanRemoval: true)]
    #[Groups(groups: ['read:User'])]
    private Collection $userRoles;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 2000, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $password = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->userRoles = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getUsername(): ?string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(?string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }
...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is your `username` property nullable while it's a not nullable ID/primary key? Also, it's a non-standard property for an identifier, so you may need to annotate it. See: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/identifiers/ Although IIRC it just gets it based on Doctrine annotations. Let me know if any ofthese helps and I'll post an answer.

Comment: @Destroy666 first thanks a lot for your help. Putting ```username``` non-nullable does not solve the issue, still the same error. As for the identifiers, I don't really understand how to implement it, although I looked at the documentation. Could you please explain?

Comment: I mean using `ApiProperty(identifier: true)` annotation like in the example on the linked website. It shouldn't matter with Doctrine annotations but worth testing just in case. Make also sure you got users all with filled usernames in your DB. If that doesn't work, I don't see anything else that's wrong in the code above that could be related to IRI, I'd recommend using a debugger to progress further and checking what it's trying to normalize in IriConverter.php:  https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/9b4b58ca0113a2645b58a116fe9e4bf200df8aa3/src/Symfony/Routing/IriConverter.php#L164